# Tridion Confirmation Email, how to add link specific for each user in it

Tags: 2011, outbound-email

I am trying to integrate the Subscription functionality, it is working fine. On subscription I am creating a contact with Unsubscribed status and using the outbound email configuration I am sending one email to user as well for confirming his subscription.

Subscription email is going to user, but how can I add a link specific to each user which I can further use in changing his subscription status to Subscribed. I am thinking to include the user's email address in the url which I can use further to get contact and update his subscription status.

Please help me by telling how can I include the user email address in the subscription confirmation link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dev Mittal please let us know which version of tridion are you using.

Comment: Dear Anand, Thanks a lot for responding!I am using Tridion 2011.

Comment: Please reply back if you have used the confirmation emails with links. I will be very helpful.

Comment: i assume you have a  page so you can add a  control called SubscriptionStatud and send the status, if the status use cofirm set the subscription  status to Optin or if the status is unsubscribe set the subscription  status to Unsubscribed. You can read the email from the contact which if you  want you can pass the email too. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, since you seem to use 'subscribe' and 'unsubscribe' interchangeably, when they are in fact polar opposites :)

But it sounds like you need to use the built-in variables that correspond to the subscribe action you want them to take: unsubscribe, opt-in (confirm subscription), or just edit their profile. The variables are covered [in the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-4CD5BC3A-2396-464C-9E2B-767DE91685EF), but for Dreamweaver templates they are:

- **@@OutboundEmail_ConfirmURL@@** for confirming the subscription (opt-in)
- **@@OutboundEmail_ChangeProfileURL@@** for changing the Contact details ('My account' type of page), and
- **@@OutboundEmail_UnsubscribeURL@@** for unsubscribing

The URLs of those links are set on the Properties of the relevant Publication.

Should the above variables not cover your use case, you will have to insert your own tracked link - and then make sure that your cd_audiencemanager_conf.xml has the AppendTrackingInfo setting set to 'true'. That way, there is a URL parameter available on the page you are linking to, which you can pass straight into the constructor of the Contact class to initialize the correct Contact.